insects dug a deep hole in a tree
There was a hole in my plum tree and some sawdust around. I thought it was a worm, but after cutting the dead branch I found a dozen of these "insects" (see picture). They were about an inch large and 1.5 inch long, with wings.
The hole was going pretty deep in the tree so I cut the branch lower and lower (hoping to see the end of the hole), until I couldn't cut more without cutting the main trunk.
The plum tree gives a lot of plums every year so I would like to save it if possible. The hole was about 3 feet long (and maybe more inside the main trunk)!
Questions:

out of curiosity, what are these insects called? (I crushed them with my feet as I was scared, but they had a pretty large stomach, almost like wood worms, they are not wasps)
what should I do about the hole that is left? is there a way to "fix the tree"?

I wondered if I should pour water into the tree (I don't know if any other insects are hiding in the hole?), or fill the hole with something so that other insects won't call it home.
Thanks



looks like a bee ... definitely not any kind of a worm ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=worm&iax=images&ia=images

the insects are using the tree as home because it has a cavity ... they probably did not make the hole ... if they are bees, then they also pollinate the plum blossoms so that you can have plums

looking online these are probably "carpenter bees" and I suspect that they dug the hole, it is exactly their size

I guess the first thing You can do is exactly the opposite of pouring water inside - make sure rain doesn't get in.

I thought carpenter bees were solitary though.
